# textAlign justify property not working in react native

Tags: react-native, text-align

I have try to use textAlign: 'justify' property in react native.TextAlign justify doesn't work on Android.
React native version: "react-native": "0.59.5"

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, View } from 'react-native';
import { Text, Button } from 'native-base';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
import { colors } from '../styles';

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.contentCenter}>
                <Text style={[styles.titleContent,styles.fontBold]}>Simple Secure</Text>
                <Text style={[styles.titleContent,styles.fontBold]}>Reliable Messaging</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
    titleContent: {
        color:'#62778c',
        fontSize: '1.4rem',
        textAlign: 'justify',
      }
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

Answer (score 3):

checkout the [offical document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/text):

> textAlign: enum('auto', 'left', 'right', 'center', 'justify')
>
> Specifies text alignment. The value 'justify' is only supported on iOS and fallbacks to left on Android.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above android does not support text justification but you can go around this by adding the html text inside WebView like this:

```
<WebView
    source={{ html: "<p style='text-align:justify;'>Your justified text</p>" }}
/>
```